# How to find dots with OpenCV in Python?

Tags: python, opencv

I'm just starting with OpenCV so this question is more like "what do you call the thing in OpenCV that does..." than "how do you do the thing..." - if I know what to look for usually docs and more googling go a long way.

So: using OpenCV in Python how could I find the position of all the black dots at the border between red and gray?

It's a nice to have if it is possible to tell if the border is horizontal or vertical or alternatively its angle at the point.

[image]

In other words - the position of the dots inside the white borders, but not the ones in the greyed out area:

[image]

Comment: work with morphology operations to remove lines. work with inRange (or numpy equivalent) to select specific colors. and DO show your own effort into solving your problem.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz - thanks! my problem is I'm just starting with OpenCV so my question is more like "what do you call the thing in OpenCV that does...". I usually know it's possible but I don't know what it's called. From there on I usually can figure things out with the documentation etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some setup:

```py
im = cv.imread("4V56c.png")
hsv = cv.cvtColor(im, cv.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
```

Dots:

```py
# axis=2 is the color dimension. all values must be at most 30.
# result is a boolean array (0 or 1). times 255 because of reasons.
dots = (im <= 30).all(axis=2) * np.uint8(255)
```

[image: dots]

Border:

```py
# a certain saturation
mask = (hsv[:,:,1] >= 50) * np.uint8(255)
# erase all the gray stuff
mask = cv.morphologyEx(src=mask, op=cv.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel=None, iterations=5)
# blow up and shrink
dilated = cv.dilate(mask, kernel=None, iterations=5)
eroded = cv.erode(mask, kernel=None, iterations=5)
# difference
border = dilated & ~eroded
```

[image: border]

Combined:

```py
dots & border
```

[image: dots & border]

Comment: thanks. To be use I understand: (1) find all the black-ish pixels (2) find the saturated pixels (they are red) (3) dilate and erode same image (4) combine the two (5) use that to mask the pixels - which gives us the border pixels. Nice. I was starting to look into gradients too. I'll try that separately.  There are a few concise things in your answer that I suspect are numpy - IÄll google thos. Thanks again

Comment: you understand the steps. yes, half of that is numpy. some more could be done in plain OpenCV C++ but... eh. OpenCV *has to* replicate in C++ what it gets for free with numpy. in C++, there are operator overloads on cv::Mat that give you mostly the same operations as numpy. OpenCV's `inRange` would be a good function to look at, if you felt like replacing some of those comparisons and `.all()` operations